# Adding multiple eventListeners using HTMLElement.prototype is not working

Tags: javascript, typescript, prototype

I extended `HTMLElement` prototype for adding multiple `eventListener`.

My Approach

```js
declare global {
  HTMLElement {
    addEventListeners(): any // with a 's'
  }
}

type CallBackFunction<T = void> = () => T

HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListeners() = function(events: Array<HTMLElementEventMap>, callback: CallBackFunction) {
  events.forEach((event) => {
    this.addEventListener(event, callback)
  })
}
```

but the above code giving me :

- `Type '(events: Array<keyof HTMLElementEventMap>, callback: CallBackFunction) => void' is not assignable to type '() => any'`
- `Object is possibly 'undefined'`

For first I tried

```js
type CallBackFunction<T = any> = () => T
```

also

```js
declare global {
  HTMLElement {
    addEventListeners(): void // with a 's'
  }
}
```

and too solve second error I even put a check but still no luck!

```js
if (typeof this !== 'undefined') {
  this.addEventListener(event, callback)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking

```
declare global {
  interface HTMLElement {
    addEventListeners<K extends keyof HTMLElementEventMap>(type: K[], listener: (this: HTMLElement, ev: HTMLElementEventMap[K]) => any, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions): void;
  }
}

HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListeners = function (events, listener) {
  events.forEach((event) => {
    this.addEventListener(event, listener);
  });
};
```

#### Usage

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListeners(['click', 'focus'], () => {
 //do something
});
```

Comment: Actually after declaring it in the global we do not need to use `prototype` it will work just fine without it!! And if we use `HTMLElement.prototype ....` the function will lose the autocomplete ness of the event listeners. So you can remove that part from the answer!!